# How to do multiple SQL LEFT JOINS of the following form?

Tags: sql, join

For simplicity; I have three tables: A, B and C

A: {ID, Value, Group}

B: {ID, Description}

C: {ID, Date}

There could be missing IDs in B and C as a result, I'm trying to do a LEFT JOIN to get the required info:

```
SELECT A.Value, A.Group, B.Description, C.Date
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID     
       LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID
```

Basically, the joins need to be of the form A LEFT JOIN B and A LEFT JOIN C
so that I can get all the required info even with missing IDs.

What is the best way to do this in SQL?

Comment: what is the problem with your query?

Comment: (1) I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results to explain what you really want.

Comment: It is the ON clause that decides what to join to. You are correctly joining B to A and C to A. Whether to first join B or C doesn't matter; it is A you are joining theses to; B and C are independent from each other in your query.

Comment: Side note: `Group` is the reserved keyword in MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle. Use proper escape characters to avoid any issues.

Comment: what you want do ? give some clear explanation

Comment: Looks fine and works in SQL Server... however, depending on you dbms you might want to try "LEFT OUTER JOIN"